# TADOQuery returns empty recordset in second execution

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

I have quite an incredible situation using a TADOQuery against an MS Access database.
In the following code (just a test case), the first execution of the query returns the correct record, the second execution instead returns an "empty" record (i.e. the codFormula variable first time is 'E0275', second time is '').

Obviously the three parameters value are the same

```
  QryDosaggioTestata.Parameters[0].Value := idBatchRottura;
  QryDosaggioTestata.Parameters[1].Value := nrMiscelataRottura;
  QryDosaggioTestata.Parameters[2].Value := dataBatchRottura;

  QryDosaggioTestata.Open;
  //  Here, QryDosaggioTestata's RecordCount is 1 and Eof is False
  codFormula := trim(QryDosaggioTestataCodiceFormula.Value);
  //now codFormula = 'E0275'
  QryDosaggioTestata.Close;

  QryDosaggioTestata.Parameters[0].Value := idBatchRottura;
  QryDosaggioTestata.Parameters[1].Value := nrMiscelataRottura;
  QryDosaggioTestata.Parameters[2].Value := dataBatchRottura;

  QryDosaggioTestata.Open;
  //  Here, QryDosaggioTestata's RecordCount is 0 and Eof is True
  codFormula := trim(QryDosaggioTestataCodiceFormula.Value);
  // now codFormula = ''
  Ora := QryDosaggioTestataOra.Value;
  QryDosaggioTestata.Close;
```

The query text is in the designer object:

```
Select * from LOG_FINE_DOSAGGIO
WHERE
idBatch = :parIdBatch
AND nrMiscelata = :parNrMiscelata
AND Data = :parData
```

Obviously the query is syntactically correct, otherwise it would not execute well the first time.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not `Close` the cursor. Call `Refresh` after you change the parameters.

Comment: Tried - not working :(

Comment: MS Access, sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: What is the `RecordCount` and `EOF` status of `QryDosaggioTestata` immediately after each call to `Open`?

Comment: First time: EOF = false, RecordCount = 1  Second time: EOF = true, RecordCount = 0

Comment: Very strange.  It is probably unrelated, but googling `ms access same query returns different result sets` returns this, amongst others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745535/ms-access-query-returns-different-results-depending-on-whether-data-local-or-on

Comment: I suggest you create a [mcve]. Settings of the connection and query components, the data access providers all could play a subtle role in the behaviour you're observing. If you make this easily verifiable without concern that you may have done something subtly yet critically different, then it will be much easier for other to help.... with the benefit to you being you're likely to get a much better answer much quicker.

Comment: Just for information: I tried the same code with a SQL Server 2014 express database and it worked like a charm...

Comment: @StefanoLosi:  Glad you found the cause.  I suggest you post your "After may attempts" comment as an answer, as it is far more likely to help future readers than the same information in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts I got the clue: the **Microsoft JET OLEDB 4.0** provider deals horribly with date parameters: the only way to make it work is, for date parameters, to set the parameter datatype to **ftString** and to pass the value as **DateToStr(yourDate)**.

My impression is that after first query.Close, the query parameters are re-prepared in the wrong way by the provider.

Hope this helps anyone. 
Everything works well with other parameters type (i.e. integer, string...) and with SQL Server provider.